# Nginx does not process the php file and saves it (php7.2-fpm)?

Tags: php, nginx, ubuntu-18.04

Nginx  does not process the php file and saves it (php7.2-fpm) Ubuntu18:04

How to set up correctly nginx for working with php7.2

## /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
   server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

    #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
```

}

## /etc/nginx/sites-available/test.ru

```
 server {

 listen 80;

 listen [::]:80;

 root /var/www/test.ru/html;

 index index.php  index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

 server_name test.ru www.test.ru;

 location / {

         try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

 }

 }
```

sudo service nginx reload
sudo nginx -t

```
 nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
 nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

What is the reason for this behavoir ? How to set it up?

Comment: Did you try copying the php portion to your second site config?

Comment: No.But i tried and it works!